# Python - I used socket to build a server to transfer a picture to myself, the codes executes, but the picture is not transferred

Tags: python, sockets

Hi I have these codes to build a client and server under my ip address to transfer a picture. The codes executes file, but the picture is never transferred to my target file. Does anyone know what is off?

This is the codes for server part
`

```
 from socket import socket, SOCK_STREAM, AF_INET
 from base64 import b64encode
 from json import dumps
 from threading import Thread


def main():
class FileTransferHandler(Thread):

    def __init__(self, cclient):
        super().__init__()
        self.cclient = cclient

    def run(self):
        my_dict = {}
        my_dict['filename'] = 'Goz.png'
        my_dict['filedata'] = data
        json_str = dumps(my_dict)
        self.cclient.send(json_str.encode('utf-8'))
        self.cclient.close()

server = socket()
server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5566))
server.listen(512)
print('Server is listening...')
with open('Goz.png', 'rb') as f:
    data = b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8')
while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    FileTransferHandler(client).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the codes for the client part
`

```
from socket import socket
from json import loads
from base64 import b64decode

def main():
    client = socket()
    client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5566))
    in_data = bytes()
    data = client.recv(1024)
    while data:
    in_data += data
    data = client.recv(1024)

my_dict = loads(in_data.decode('utf-8'))
filename = my_dict['filename']
filedata = my_dict['filedata'].encode('utf-8')
with open('/Users/bowenduan/Desktop/Hao' + filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b64decode(filedata))
print('Picture saved.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try to debug your code on server and client side. Just put print(1), print(2), etc. after every line

Comment: Is your file perhaps being written as `'HaoGoz.png'` when you expect it to be `'Hao/Goz.png'`?

Comment: @Blckknght You're absolutely right! I made a dumb mistake and didn't notice!

Answer (score 1):

```
#at the sending side read the image and convert the dictionary into a string

pic = open('img.jpg','rb')

textcode = pic.read()


mydata = {
    'pic' : textcode,
    'name' : 'img.jpg'
}
newcode = str(mydata)

##at the recieving side 

#size depends on the size of data you are going to recieve
mydata = sock.recv(24000).decode()

newfile = open('new.jpg','wb+') #jpg/jpeg/png/etc
newfile.write(eval(mydata)['pic'])
newfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to have been a filename handling one, not a problem with the actual networking parts of the code. Your client code was expected to save its files into a folder named `Hao`, but instead your code was using that as the prefix to the filename to be written. So instead of `Hao/Goz.png`, you were getting `HaoGoz.png`.

The way to avoid this kind of issue is to use standard library code to handle your paths, rather than doing string manipulation directly. Either the older `os.path.join`, or the newer `pathlib.Path` are probably your best bets:

```
import os.path

folder = '/Users/bowenduan/Desktop/Hao'

# later...
filename = 'Gao.png'
full_filename = os.path.join(folder, filename)
```

Or:

```
import pathlib

folder_path = pathlib.Path('/Users/bowenduan/Desktop/Hao')

# later...
filename = 'Gao.png'
full_filename = folder_path / filename
```